# Inserting rows from one table into different tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having trouble with this, and hope someone can help. I have a single-column table with string rows with strings delimited columns by pipe, as shown below.

*** column1 ***

aa  |   1    |   2

bb  |   3    |   4   |   5

cc  |   6

dd  |   7    |   8   |   9   |   0

Here, we have 4 rows from the original tables, which should be ingested into 4 tables. The tables are indicated by the first 2 characters for the row. So we have aa, bb, cc, and dd target tables. The rows are such that one can't use pipe or comma as delimiters for ingestion because the fields contain those characters, and each table has different table definitions. Let's say the field names for the 4 tables are aa: i , j; bb: k, l, m; cc: p; dd: r, s, t, u.

I have done some googling, and most of what I see points to dynamic SQL or some sp as in below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.IngestRows
(
  @InputTable VARCHAR(255),
  @OutputTable1 VARCHAR(255),
  @OutputTable2 VARCHAR(255),
  @OutputTable3 VARCHAR(255),
  @OutputTable4 VARCHAR(255)
)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Row VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE @Count INT;
  DECLARE @MaxCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @InputTable);
  DECLARE @CaseStatement VARCHAR(255);

  -- Set the CASE statement to select the appropriate output table based on the value of the `Category` column
  SET @CaseStatement = 'CASE WHEN @Row LIKE = ''aa%'' THEN @OutputTable1 
                             WHEN @Row LIKE = ''bb%'' THEN @OutputTable2
                             WHEN @Row LIKE = ''cc%'' THEN @OutputTable3
                             ELSE @OutputTable4
                        END';

  -- Iterate through the rows in the input table
  WHILE @Count <= @MaxCount
    BEGIN
      -- Get the next row from the input table
      SET @Row = (SELECT TOP (1) * FROM @InputTable ORDER BY [Id] ASC);

      -- Insert the row into the appropriate output table based on the value of the `Category` column
      INSERT INTO @CaseStatement ([Id], [Category], [Name]) VALUES (@Row.[Id], @Row.[Category], @Row.[Name]);
    SET @Count = @Count + 1
    END
END
GO
```

The problem I have is since the tables are different and not the same, and I have to do some LEFT and RIGHT string selection to define the data for each field parameter for each row, how can I do this with the above CASE statement for inserts of each row? I am having issues with the names and values part of the Insert statement when switching from table to table and how that string selection will come into play. Thanks for the help in advance. Much appreciated!

**Source table definition**

column1 varchar(max) not null

**Target table definition**

*table aa*

i varchar(2) not null

j varchar(2) not null

*table bb*

k varchar(2) not null

l varchar(2) not null

m varchar(2) not null

*table cc*

p varchar(2) not null

*table dd*

r varchar(2) not null

s varchar(2) not null

t varchar(2) not null

u varchar(2) not null

One can make the data field length anything, but for this example, length 2 is fine.

Comment: *The rows are such that one can't use pipe or comma as delimiters for ingestion because the fields contain those characters* - how does one then split those rows into columns?

Comment: The way I have found is using LEFT and RIGHT string selection. Let's say at the input table when you select a row, you use that string selection. So, for example if input row has row #1 as @row varchar(100) = 'aa|1|2|3', we do LEFT(@row, 2) for first field, RIGHT(LEFT(@row, 4), 1) for second field etc., Then this will be saved in some parameters that are the values for the insert. Still, it will be complicated because one will do that for the different tables. I am looking for a way to do this that is efficient, or that works. Thanks for your response.

Comment: hmm, but why not just use string_split then?

Comment: string_split requires you to provide either a character you're splitting by e.g. "|" or something like "," or their character value like maybe char(10) or whichever it is. That won't work for this because if you have a row = aa|12|xyx|,zz|247. That is 3 columns, but if you use that function, you get 4 columns if you are counting without the 'aa', which is just a table indicator. There are cases where column delimiters don't work. A more complicated way to solve this is using some external function, but easier to just capture the string with the string selection so selecting the column length

Comment: ok, but how do *you* as developer know which is column in aa|12|xyx|,zz|247

Comment: what was the motivation behind storing unquoted values in a row where delimeters can also exist in data

Comment: Good question, @siggemannen. That is in the table definition for tables. I will edit my original post to include the table structure for each target tables. Thanks, Sumant Kumar Mandal.

Comment: @siggemannen, LOL. That is the real world. Some data are dirty from the source, with no input validation, and end users can enter whatever they want. The data is all text values and the table definitions are separate. So, this is a challenge for the client. Thanks

Comment: In that case, Dirty data will lead to incorrect values in those rows. Might be last column will get all remained data. It will depend on store procedure.

Comment: Could you please add structure of all tables ? InputTable , OutputTable1, OutputTable2, OutputTable3 & OutputTable4.

Comment: I solved this using temp tables, but it can blow up quickly depending on the number of target tables. Here, you extract each row to a temp table; then, you can do bulk or individual inserts from there. 

So, I am looking at inserting each of the rows one at a time with little or no temp tables, but having trouble.

Comment: @Sumant Kumar Mandal, the input table is just one column with varchar(max), not null.

Comment: Will be there only 4 target tables, or it might increase ?

Comment: This is easy to do in Python, Scala, or Java by creating a dictionary for lookups.  I am looking at something similar with a lookup table with a predefined table definition one can call in the INSERT statement for VALUES and column names. Not sure if that is efficient. So, thanks for helping everyone.

Comment: @SumantKumarMandal. There are over 60 target tables, but that question shows 4. The concept is the same, so it should scale to any number of tables. 
So we are saying: 
1. starting from row #1 down to the last row in a sequential order in the WHILE loop 
2. if the first 2 characters of the rows match a table type
3. split the row based on string selection or that match to a predefined string selection that matches the table definition for that table type 
4. insert into matching table with maybe the CASE statement 
5. Move to the next row down, repeat

The challenge is mostly #2 & #3

Comment: <pedantry> [`Case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is an _expression_, not a _statement_, in T-SQL. </pedantry>

Answer (score 1):

as alternative approach

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (col varchar(50))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES
('aa |1|2'),
('bb | 3 | 4 | 5'),
('cc | 6'),
('dd | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0')

SELECT dbo.fn_buildDynamicSQL(tablename, col)
FROM 
    (SELECT CASE LEFT(RTRIM(LTRIM(col)), 2) 
        WHEN 'aa' THEN 'aTable'
        WHEN 'bb' THEN 'bTable'
        WHEN 'cc' THEN 'cTable'
        ELSE 'dTable' END AS tablename, col 
    FROM @t ) c
```

and function need to be adjusted base on table name

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_buildDynamicSQL 
(
    @tableName NVARCHAR(50),
    @row NVARCHAR(max)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(max)
AS
BEGIN
    
    RETURN 'select * from ' + @tableName

END
GO
```

then look at this url as example how to exec dynamic sql row by row.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118893/execute-dynamic-sql-generated-from-select

Comment: Thanks for your response. I solved the same without the function using EXEC sp_executesql. I used the CASE expression to map the first two characters to the tables in a WHILE loop. Then, for each row with that match, I built the INSERT statement dynamically using the following: table name from CASE expression, columns names from sys.columns using the matched name as object_id, and then for the values, I swapped the pipe for comma. That worked. 


However, though, I am still looking at casting or converting those values in that INSERT statement. Otherwise, I will catch those as exceptions.